# Python Scrapy on offline (local) data

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a 270MB dataset (10000 html files) on my computer. Can I use Scrapy to crawl this dataset locally? How?

Answer (score 34):

## SimpleHTTP Server Hosting

If you truly want to host it locally and use scrapy, you could serve it by navigating to the directory it's stored in and run the SimpleHTTPServer (port 8000 shown below):

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Then just point scrapy at 127.0.0.1:8000

```
$ scrapy crawl 127.0.0.1:8000
```

## file://

An alternative is to just have scrapy point to the set of files directly:

```
$ scrapy crawl file:///home/sagi/html_files # Assuming you're on a *nix system
```

## Wrapping up

Once you've set up your scraper for scrapy (see [example dirbot](https://github.com/scrapy/dirbot)), just run the crawler:

```
$ scrapy crawl 127.0.0.1:8000
```

If links in the html files are absolute rather than relative though, these may not work well. You would need to adjust the files yourself.

Comment: You do realize that awarding the bonus to yourself won't earn you a hat, right? :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm giving out bounties on several. Happy Holidays! On some level, I was hoping the asker would accept an answer. :-/

Comment: Your answer is certainly thorough enough to deserve at least *some* feedback, indeed!

Comment: For python 3.1: python -m http.server

Answer (score 9):

Go to your Dataset folder :

```
import os
files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
for file in files:
    with open(file,"r") as f:
        page_content = f.read()
        #do here watever you want to do with page_content. I guess parsing with lxml or Beautiful soup.
```

No need to go for Scrapy !

Comment: There are so many functionalities that Scrapy provides, e.g., multiple options to get the same field. Of course, you can replicate all these functionalities but that would be reinventing the wheel.